# Scanner Resource Leak

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, args, resource-leak, try-finally

Today I have written a Java code that reads input from 2 txt files named input1.txt and input2.txt and solves 2 programming problems. It runs from the terminal like:

```
java berkSol input1.txt input2.txt
```

I am reading my inputs with Scanner in the program. I have got 2 Scanner object. My code is basically like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class berkSol {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        if(args.length > 0) {   

            // The Solution of Problem1 begins
            File file1 = new File(args[0]);
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(file1); // The Scanner that is going to read file1.
            try {
                .
                .
                .
                // The Solution of Problem 2 begins
               File file2 = new File(args[1]);
                reader = new Scanner(file2); // The Scanner that is going to read file2.
                .
                .
                .
            }
            finally {
                if(reader!=null)
                reader.close();
            }
        } // End Of Check on the Arguments Length   
    } // End of Main
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Visual Studio Code was giving me warning about resource leak, so I have added that finally block in the end. But now, it is giving that exact same warning for the inner Scanner. I am not using the Scanner that reads file1 after I initialize it to file2. I thought that because their names are the same, when I close after the try block the second one would not leak any resource too.

My program is working but I don't know if there can be any problem because of the resource leak.

Can anyone tell me why my second scanner is leaking and what can I do to prevent it and what bad can happen if I don't fix it?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: easy fix is to use `try-with-resource`. I never had anything bad happen with any resource leak I had

Comment: I'll check that out in a minute. Thanks.

Comment: `reader = new Scanner(file2)` overrides reference to your first scanner, so the first one is never closed.

Comment: You are only closing the second reader. You should close both of them ideally. NOTE: When you exit, all resources are closed anyway. Wasting one file handle is hardly likely to matter in this case.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Am I closing the second one? I thought I was closing the first one. But it gives the warning at the second one not the first one. Are you sure?

Comment: @BerkUtkuYenisey it closes whatever `reader` was set to last.  It closes the first one if an exception/error occurs before opening the second one which is fine. If the second one replaces the first one, only it will be closed.

Comment: Code analysers are often confused by code, however if you write code which confused the analyser, I suggest you consider making it less confusing. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok now it makes sense :D. Thank you all for answering.

Comment: I have changed the inner Scanner as reader2 and added another try-finally block under it. Now there are no warnings. But I am a bit curious is it safe to have more than 1 Scanners at a time since they are sharing the stream?

Comment: You can have as many Scanners as you want (within reason) and they are not sharing anything. I suggest you close the first scanner before using the second. If you use try-with-resource it will close them for you.